# Python Web Scraping - How to submit post information

Tags: python, firebug

I found another post in which I couldn't figure out part of an answer:

[a (presumably basic) web scraping of http://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi in urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220997/a-presumably-basic-web-scraping-of-http-www-ssa-gov-cgi-bin-popularnames-cgi)

The top answer says that the user used Firebug in order to figure out the different parameters that were being passed by inspecting the network activity.

I can't figure out how to do this or where I can see this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [download](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) and install firebug
2. browse to the page that include the form you want
3. right click and choose `Inspect Element with Firebug`
4. go to net panel,you may have to activate it and reload the page on first use

see firebug [net panel wiki page](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel)

[image]

you'd usually hit the `clear` button before pressing the form submit